# The path specified in the 'TestAdapterPath' is invalid. Travis .net

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, travis-ci

```
The path ';/home/travis/.nuget/packages/coverlet.collector/1.0.1/build/netstandard1.0/' specified in the 'TestAdapterPath' is invalid. Error: The custom test adapter search path provided was not found, provide a valid path and try again.
```

Why does this error occur?
I tried test my project with unit tests using this library `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting`.

It is my .travis.yml file:

```
language: csharp
mono: none
os: linux
dotnet: 2.0.0
dist: xenial
before_script: 
    - dotnet restore ".\Travis.Tests.Build\TravisBuild\TravisBuild.sln"
script: 
    - dotnet build ".\Travis.Tests.Build\TravisBuild\TravisBuild.sln" -c Debug
    - dotnet test ".\Travis.Tests.Build\TravisBuild\TravisBuild.sln" -c Debug
```

I am using .netstandard2.0.
The second project "TestProject" tests the functionality of the first one.
Perhaps I have indicated a little information, please specify what else is needed to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: you need to remove the nugget package "coverlet.collector". I don't understand where it comes from in my project, but without it everything is fine.
It may have been installed with other nuget packages as a nuget relationship.